# Fazer import de um outro módulo de detro de um outro utilizando macros LibreOffice

Tags: python, libreoffice

Esta questão refere-se a utilização de macros em python no LibreOffice.
Andei fazendo alguns estudos sobre o assunto e verifiquei que um dos meios de se adicionar uma macro escrita em Python ao LibreOffice seria colocá-la no diretório: `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python`.
Até aí tudo bem, mas eu gostaria de ir um passo adiante. Quando se desenvolve programas maiores, muitas vezes é necessário dividi-lo em vários módulos. Consequentemente teríamos, no caso dos módulos mod_A.py e mod_B.py num mesmo projeto:

`import mod_B # Estando em mod_A`

No entanto, quando tento executar a macro do modulo mod_A através de [Ferramentas > Organizar Macros > Python] > mod_A > uma_das_funcoes obtenho uma grande mensagem de erro informado que mod_B não foi encontrado.

> com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeExceptionError during invoking function main in module file:///usr/lib/libreoffice/share/Scripts/python/Balanco.py (: name 'getMovimentoGeral' is not defined
>     /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/Scripts/python/Balanco.py:41 in function main() [movimento = getMovimentoGeral(model, sheets)]
>     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/pythonscript.py:869 in function invoke() [ret = self.func( *args )]
>   )

Complementando. Informo que `Balanco.py` e `Movimento.py` estão na mesma pasta a qual foi indicada acima.

Em resumo: gostaria de saber se alguém tem conhecimento sobre o como fazer import de um módulo do projeto dentro de uma macro em python desenvolvida para o LibreOffice / OpenOffice.

Realmente, por um engano meu, não percebi que a mensagem de erro que transcrevi acima não se tratava de um erro de importação. No entanto, garanto que em testes subsequentes recebi mensagens informando que não se encontrava Movimento.
De qualquer modo, percebi pelo link que me enviaram, que poderia adicionar o caminho para a pasta das macro a sys.path. Sendo assim inseri o seguinte comando no no início do programa:

```
sys.path.append('/home/jorge/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/')
```

que é o local das macros no LibreOffice / OpenOffice.
Em seguida inseri o import do modulo desejado.

Talvez seja melhor inserir o código do módulo principal.

```
`Arquivo: Balanco.py
@author: Jorge Luiz
Aquivo principal da aplicação (teste) para totalização do balanço geral de        uma planliha
voltada para controle de despesas de um condoínio.
Há uma aba para cada mês do ano, sendo que o balanço final do mês é   transferido para o mês seguinte.
@note: A coluna dos valores é "C"
@attention: foi encontrada uma dificuldade na execução de import de   módulos locais, no caso Movimento.py
o que foi resolvido adicionando-se o caminho do local do script a sys.path
Este é o arquivo pricipal da aplicação / macro para rodar numa planilha   específica do Calc.
Depende do módulo Movimento
'''
import sys
from datetime import date

lSheets = ('JAN', 'FEV', 'MAR', 'ABR', 'MAI', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AGO', 'SET',
       'OUT', 'NOV', 'DEZ')

__debug = False     #Mudar __debug para False quando for distribuir.

def init():
    '''
    Obter model no contexto de uma instância do LibreOffice  já executando.
    @todo: Tendo em vista que esta é uma macro para um arquivo específico:
    1: Tentar inserir a macro no próprio arquivo OU
    2. Fazer a verificação do nome do arquivo.
    '''

    desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()
    model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()

    #Graças ao comando abaixo é possível reconhecer os imports (import Movimento)
    #Obs: não aceita caminho: ~/
    sys.path.append('/home/jorge/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/')

    return model


def main():
    # access the active sheet
    if not __debug:
         model = init()

    else:
        #Quando em modo de depuração.
        import initOO
        model = initOO.initOO()

    import Movimento    #Esse import deve ficar após as inicializções.

    if not model:
        print('Falha ao obter model')
        sys.exit(1)

    anoSimpl = str(date.today().year)[-2:]
    nomesSheets = []
    for sheet in lSheets:
        nomesSheets.append(sheet + ' ' + anoSimpl)

    print('Lendo Planilhas...')   
    lMov = Movimento.getMovimentoGeral(model, nomesSheets)

    print('Escevendo movimento financeiro')

    sheetResumo = model.Sheets.getByName('RESUMO')
    Movimento.escreveMovimento(sheetResumo, lMov)

    print('Planilha%12s' % 'VALOR')
    valorTotal = 0.0
    for mov in lMov:
        print(mov['sheet'])
        valorMensal = 0.0
        for valor in mov['movimento']:
            valorMensal += valor
            valorTotal += valor
            print ('%21.2f' % valor)


        print('Saldo no mês:%8.2f\n' % valorMensal)

    print('Saldo final %9.2f' % valorTotal)

    receita,despesa = Movimento.getReceitasDespesas(lMov)

    print('RESUMO ---------------------------------')
    print('Receita:%13.2f\ndespesa:%13.2f\nsaldo:  %13.2f' %(receita, despesa, receita + despesa))

if __name__ == '__main__':    #Essa parte é só para debug.
    main() 
    print ('FIM')

g_exportedScripts = main,
```

`

Dessa forma consegui fazer com que a macro rodasse no LibreOffice dentro do arquivo desejado.
Portanto considero resolvido o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Espere -

Você não teve uma mensagem de erro no seu import  -
talvez você só não esteja familiarizado com Python

A função do outro módulo vai estar disponível como

```
Mod_B.getMovimentoGeral
```

após um `import Mod_B`.

Se não quiser precisar colocar os prefixos dos módulos no código, pode usar uma das outras formas do import, como:

```
from Mod_B import getMovimentoGeral
```

Comment: Realmente me enganei ao copiar a mensagem, mas garanto que havia recebido, anteriormente, uma mensagem de erro no import. Acho que o diferencial nesta questão é que se trata de código Python visando ser executado como macro num arquivo do LibreOffice / OpenOffice. Normalmente não haveria erro no import, mas por alguma peculiaridade no ambiente de macros surge esse erro desconcertante.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque os módulos ou pacotes nesse diretório

```
~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/pythonpath
```

Arquivo: `user/Scripts/python/test.py`.

```
def test():
    import hello
    hello.do_hello()

g_exportedScripts = test,
```

Arquivo: `user/Scripts/python/pythonpath/hello.py`.

```
def do_hello():
    f = open('hello.txt', 'w')
    print("Hello", file=f)
```

[Documentação em inglês](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python#Importing_Modules).

Comment: I translated your answer for pt-br :), you could use a translater next time, but no problem now

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Parece que funcionou. Criei a pasta `pythonpath` em `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/` e lá criei um link simbólico para o módulo referenciado.

Comment: Por favor, [acepte esta respuesta](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=pt-BR&u=https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) si se soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tendo em vista organizar explicar aquilo que foi feito informo o seguinte:
Inicialmente, observando no link que rray me passou, percebi que poderia adicionar o `path` para o módulo referenciado (no caso Movimento.py) fazendo: `sys.path.append('/home/jorge/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/') #Não aceita ~/` em Balanco.py. Essa solução funcionou.
Posteriormente, seguindo ainda a mesma recomendação de rray, criei a pasta ´pythonpath´ em '~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/' e depois criei um link simbólico para ´Movimento.py´ em ´pythonpath´. Também comentei a linha que adicionava o caminho para a pasta das macros: `#sys.path.append('/home/jorge/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/') #Não aceita ~/`. Essa solução também funcionou.
Conclusão
As duas soluções funcionaram, mas parece que a segunda proposta favorece a distribuição da macro em outros computadores e ainda no Windows, se não me engano. 
Coloco a seguir os códigos

Balanco.py
´

```
'''
Arquivo: Balanco.py
@author: Jorge Luiz
Aquivo principal da aplicação (teste) para totalização do balanço geral de     uma planliha
voltada para controle de despesas de um condoínio.
Há uma aba para cada mês do ano, sendo que o balanço final do mês é       transferido para o mês seguinte.
@note: A coluna dos valores é "C"
@attention: foi encontrada uma dificuldade na execução de import de    módulos locais, no caso Movimento.py
o que foi resolvido adicionando-se o caminho do local do script a sys.path
Este é o arquivo pricipal da aplicação / macro para rodar numa planilha          específica do Calc.
Depende do módulo Movimento
'''
import sys
from datetime import date

lSheets = ('JAN', 'FEV', 'MAR', 'ABR', 'MAI', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AGO', 'SET',
       'OUT', 'NOV', 'DEZ')

__debug = False     #Mudar __debug para False quando for distribuir.

def init():
'''
Obter model no contexto de uma instância do LibreOffice  já executando.
'''

desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()
model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()

#Graças ao comando abaixo é possível reconhecer os imports (import Movimento)
#Obs: não aceita caminho: ~/
#sys.path.append('/home/jorge/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/')

return model


def main():
    nomeSheetResumo = 'RESUMO'

    if not __debug:
        model = init()

    else:
        #Quando em modo de depuração.
        import initOO
        model = initOO.initOO()

    import Movimento    #Esse import deve ficar após as inicializções.

    if not model:
    print('Falha ao obter model')
    sys.exit(1)

    anoSimpl = str(date.today().year)[-2:]

    nomesSheets = []
    for sheet in lSheets:
        nomesSheets.append(sheet + ' ' + anoSimpl)

    movimento = Movimento.Movimento(model.Sheets, nomesSheets)

    movimento.escreveMovimento(nomeSheetResumo)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() 
    print ('FIM')

g_exportedScripts = main,´
```

Em seguida Movimento.py

```
'''
Created on 19 de nov de 2017

@author: jorge
'''


class Movimento():
    '''
    Para os movimentos financeiros do balanço do condomínio
    '''

    def __init__(self, sheets, lNomesSheets):
        '''
        Construtor.
        @param sheets: as abas da planilha.
        @param lNomesSheets: lista de nomes das planilhas onde procurar os movimentos. Geralmente os mêses.
        '''
        self.sheets = sheets                #As abas da planilha.
        self.lNomesSheets = lNomesSheets    #Lista de nomes das planilhas que devem conter os movimentos.


    def getMovimentoSheet(self, sheet, linIni=0):
        '''
        Obter os valores do movimento de uma aba da planilha passada como parâmetro
        @param sheet: a aba a ser lida.
        @param linIni: linha inicial a ser lida (índice). A primeira linha é zero.
        @return: dicionário {'sheet': 'nome_da_aba', 'valores': (lista_de_valores)}
        '''
        colDesc = 0
        colData = 1
        colVal = 2

        lin = linIni

        movSheet = []

        while 1:
            lin += 1
            #Verificar se ainda há linhas (movimento) para serem lidadas.
            cel = sheet.getCellByPosition(colDesc,lin)
            if cel.String.strip() == 'TOTAL'or (not cel.String):
                break

            descricao = cel.String.strip()
            data = sheet.getCellByPosition(colData, lin).getValue()
            valor = sheet.getCellByPosition(colVal, lin).getValue()

            dictMov = {'descricao': descricao, 'data': data, 'valor': valor}

            movSheet.append(dictMov)

        return movSheet


    def getMovimentoGeral(self):
        '''
        Obter uma lista com todos os itens de receita e despesa do movimento financeiro da planilha.
        @return: lista de dicionários keys('descricao', 'data', 'valor').
        '''
        movimentoGeral = []
        lin = 0
        for nomeSheet in self.lNomesSheets:
            if not self.sheets.hasByName(nomeSheet):
                #Não há todos os meses na planilha.
                continue

            sheet = self.sheets.getByName(nomeSheet)

            movMes = self.getMovimentoSheet(sheet, lin)
            movimentoGeral.extend(movMes)
            lin = 1 #A linha aqui não é zerada por que considera-se que nas abas subsequentes a primeira
                    #linha refe-se ao valor TRANSPORTADO da planilha anterior o qual não deve ser computado.

        return movimentoGeral


    def escreveMovimento(self, nomeSheetResumo):
        '''
        Escrever todos os itens de receita e despesa na aba de resumo, além de totalizar.
        @param nomeSheetResumo: o nome da aba para a escrita do resumo.
        '''
        colDescr = 0 
        colData = 1
        colValor = 2


        if not self.sheets.hasByName(nomeSheetResumo):
            ns = self.sheets.getCount()
            self.sheets.insertNewByName(nomeSheetResumo , ns )

        sheetResumo = self.sheets.getByName(nomeSheetResumo)

        lMov = self.getMovimentoGeral()

        valorTotal = 0.0
        lin = 1
        for mov in lMov:
            cellDescr = sheetResumo.getCellByPosition(colDescr, lin)
            cellData = sheetResumo.getCellByPosition(colData, lin)
            cellValor = sheetResumo.getCellByPosition(colValor, lin)

            cellDescr.setString(mov['descricao'])
            cellData.setValue(mov['data'])
            cellValor.setValue(mov['valor'])

            valorTotal += mov['valor']

            lin += 1

        sheetResumo.getCellByPosition(colValor, lin).setValue(valorTotal)




g_exportedScripts = Movimento,
```